# How to position a 3D crosshair on an objects face and set its angles **outward** from objects face?

Tags: 3d, vector, three.js

What I have right now, is a ray tracer for my cursor on my canvas, when I click on the object, it gets the vector of my selection in the 3D space on the object I had my mouse on.

The ray tracer returns a `point` which is a `Vector3`, so I set my crosshairs (`line`) position to `point`, only issue is, I need my crosshair to be pointing outward from my object like so: (example)

[image]

This is where my issue lies... I need to get the direction of the **face** that my ray tracer intersected, but I cant figure out how. I can get the direction of the object itself no problem,but I dont want that, I want my crosshair to lie flat **on** the face that its positioned on.

This is it incorrectly positioned on the side of my model:

[image]

So the line thats pointing outward from the cross, should point outward from the face and the cross be flat on the surface I clicked.

This is the code Im using now:

```
line.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
var mx = new THREE.Matrix4().lookAt(intersects[0].point,new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0), intersects[0].normal);
var qt = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromRotationMatrix(mx);
line.rotation.copy(qt);
```

**Update**

I've tried another approach as seen [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/GX9Pq4AC58yK4lWONjMF?p=preview) but Im still haing trouble getting it to flatten out on the mesh:

```
var mat = intersects[0].object.matrixWorld;
    mat.setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    var globalNormal = intersects[0].face.normal.clone().applyMatrix4(mat).normalize();
    var lookAtTagret = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(intersects[0].point.clone(), globalNormal);
    line.lookAt(lookAtTagret);
    var cPos = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(intersects[0].point, globalNormal.multiplyScalar(0.05))
    line.position.copy(cPos)
```

Comment: You'll need to either inspect the vertices of the object, check which face got hit and calculate it's normal or try using a dofferent method for click detection instead. You could draw the objects to a pixel buffer, using a shader you could make the pixel encode the id of the object and the normals at that position (you have 4 bytes, 2 bytes for the id (65536 possible objects) and 2 bytes for the normals should suffice), then when you click you get the pixel color at that position and get the normal.

Comment: @Bálint I've given that a shot with the following:

```line.lookAt(intersects[0].face.normal);```

This kind of works, but the angles are totally off... I can rotate _after_ doing `lookAt` but obviously, this wouldnt then work for all faces. Any ideas? Thanks! http://imgur.com/a/x40GC

Comment: Ive jut setup an example to demonstrate my issue. I've tried a different approach here to see if it made a difference https://plnkr.co/edit/GX9Pq4AC58yK4lWONjMF?p=preview